# C3js dynamic load unknown columns

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have an empty timeseries chart with c3js and would like to "load" dynamically columns from a unknown map.

**Initialization**

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'ts',
        xFormat: null, // For millis
        columns: []
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    },
    line: { // For enable null values in series (gaps in charts))
        connectNull: false 
    }
});
```

**I add the x axis values and dynamically generated map with all data:**

```
var tsData = ['ts'].concat(VALUES_FROM_ANOTHER_FUNCTION);
periodPowerChart.load({
    columns: [
        tsData
    ]
});
// opMode looks like [{"1": [null, null, 0, 3, 5]}, {"2": [2, 4, null, null, null]}]
for (key in opMode) {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            [key].concat(opMode[key])
        ]
    })
}
```

So the idea is loading data from `opMode`. In the first iteration in the for i got:

```
Error: x is not defined for id = "1"
```

The 3 arrays (ts, "1" and "2" have same number of elements). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting a invalid data format to the columns parameter.
You should provide something like below to the columns.

```
var columnsData = [[
  "ts",
  "2013-01-01",
  "2013-01-02",
  "2013-01-03",
  "2013-01-04",
  "2013-01-05"
],
[
  "data1",
  null,
  null,
  0,
  3,
  5
],
[
  "data2",
  2,
  4,
  null,
  null,
  null
]];
```

I updated your dynamic column inserting logic to make data look like above.
Here's the code.

```
//opMode should look like below with time data.
var opMode = [{
  "ts": ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05']
}, {
  "data1": [null, null, 0, 3, 5]
}, {
  "data2": [2, 4, null, null, null]
}];

opMode.forEach(function(obj, index) {
  var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  var data = [key];

  data = data.concat(obj[key]);

  chart.load({
    columns: [
      data
    ]
  });

});
```

You can refer this example and play with it to get a good idea.
http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html

Comment: Yeah! Just solved right now before see your comment. In fact the problem was not refered to the data type, just need to join all the columns in a unique object `data` (in your case) and call once `chart.load` function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone else in another approach.

In my case the problem was related to loading multiple times data. Just joining all the column data in a single array solves the issue:

```
var columnsData = [];
var tsData = ['ts'].concat(VALUES_FROM_ANOTHER_FUNCTION);
columnsData.push(tsData);
for (key in opMode) {
    columnsData.push([key].concat(opMode[key]));
}
chart.load({
    columns: columnsData
});
```